# what to use any protocol in cloud?

Tags: tcp

I am currently studying alone computer networking.
I am wondering if I will download a movie file to my laptop in the cloud enviroment, Should I use any protocol?
Because of the size of a movie , it is important to speed fast.

Thanks for reading .I am not familiar with the English language.
please answer my question. thank you!

Comment: What, specifically do you mean by protocol? What protocol does your application use?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you talk about streaming, then UDP is preferable.
Because of low overhead and supports time critical transport, while risking packet loss.

If you talk about file transfer, then TCP is preferable.
Because of guaranteed transport, but no support for time critical transport.